# Change parameter syntax on form submit

Tags: php, forms, date, parameters

I am working on this form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <label>Ankomst</label> <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="p_arr" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y');?>"/>
    <label>Avreise </label><input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="p_dep" value="<?php echo date ('d/m/Y', strtotime(' +1 day'));?>"/>

    <label>Personer </label><select name="p_pax">
        <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And need to change the parameter syntax on form submit from:

```
http://localhost:8888/booking%20form/index.php?p_arr=31%2F01%2F2019&p_dep=01%2F02%2F2019&p_pax=1
```

To:

```
localhost:8888/booking%20form/index.php?p_arr=20190131_0000&p_dep=20190201_0000&p_pax=1_1_1
```

I have tried with this code for to change the date syntax:

```
<?php
if(isset ($_GET['submit'])){
  $date = date('Ymd_000', strtotime($_POST['date']));
}
?>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({minDate: "+0"});
  });
</script>
```

How kan I change the syntax from ('d/m/Y') to ('Ymd_000) and p_pax to 1_1_1, on form submit?

Appreciate help on this one...

Comment: `$_GET['submit']` __is not set__.

Comment: Why is there a ```strtotime($_POST['date'])``` if you send your data via GET?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Why you want to change the url like that? Your selection input will only return one value right?

Comment: I am passing arrival and departure dates, pluss number of persons in a form on the front page to the booking page.

Answer (score 0):

**For p_pax=1_1_1:**

```
<select name="p_pax">
    <option selected="selected" value="1_1_1">1</option>
    <option value="2_2_2">2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

**For your format date:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker({
        minDate: "+0",
        dateFormat: "yymmdd'_000'"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing values before send form when you can't edit HTML code.

**Changes in your HTML (adding attributes id):**

```
<form action="index.php" id="form1" method="get">
...
<select id="p_pax" name="p_pax">
...
```

**jQuery script:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker({
        minDate: "+0"
    });

    $("#form1").on( "submit", function() {
        $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yymmdd'_0000'");
        var val = $("#p_pax option:selected").val();
        $("#p_pax option:selected").val(val + "_" + val + "_" + val);
    });
});
```

*But it is a bad solution when a user will have JS off.*